# Twitter Bootstrap 3 - max height, custom layout

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, layout, twitter-bootstrap-3, css

I have something like this:

```
+-------------------------------------------+
|             -- navigation --              |
+------+------------------------------------+
|      |                                    |
| left |                                    |
| side |                                    |
| with |                                    |
| affix|           -- content (white) --    |
| menu |                                    |
|-black|                                    |
|      |                                    |
|      |                                    |
|      +------------------------------------+
|      |           -- footer (white) --     |
+------+------------------------------------+
```

as my layout in TB 3.0, and some code:

```
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12>-- navigation (height = 50px) here --</div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">-- left side with black background here --</div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">-- content with white background here --</div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">-- footer (height = 50px) with white background here --</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I want make my left side (with black background) and content (white background) with height = 100% of my browser window and footer (white background) below my content to be visible (also on scroll).

For now, I get height of last element of the side. If my content is short, it ends for example in the center of vertical side of my browser.

Here is it: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FxImy

Comment: Man, it is really confusing trying to follow all of that by way of explanation - can you throw some code on codepen.io and link to it?

Comment: I am so sorry :) I forgot about that. I edited my question and I added link at the end.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Pure CSS Solution (using calc)

If you can use CSS3, and this `50px` height is static, you can use `calc` to achieve your layout.

Here's a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/TNb3p/)

**HTML**

```
<header>
        Header
</header>
<div id="Container">
    <div id="Left">I'm in the left menu</div>
    <div id="Right">
        <div id="Content">Content</div>
        <footer>Footer</footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
*
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
html, body
{
    height: 100%;
}

header, footer
{
    height: 50px;

    background-color: yellow;
    text-align: center;
}
#Container, #Content
{
    height: calc(100% - 50px);
    overflow: auto;
}
#Left, #Right
{
    height: 100%;
}
#Left
{
    float: left;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
#Right
{
    overflow: auto;
}
```

If the height is not static, I have another solution for you, that I demonstrate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19219792/3-column-css-layout-with-sticky-footer-columns-100-height/19220042#19220042) it's not excatly your layout, but it can be done the same way.

Comment: Just a detail: "Fotter" should be "Footer"... :-)

Answer (score 1):

See if this example helps you out: http://bootply.com/87811

It basically wraps the columns in a container, sets 100% height, and makes the navbar, sidebar and footer `position:fixed`

Comment: But top navigation and footer should be scrollable. It can not be fixed :)

Answer (score -1):

Your problem seems the footer only? (or content height).
Set the footer fixed / sticky (http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/) when your content is too small by jquery.

something like:

css from http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/sticky-footer.css:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  /* The html and body elements cannot have any padding or margin. */
}

/* Wrapper for page content to push down footer */
.wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  /* Negative indent footer by its height */
  margin: 0 auto -60px;
  /* Pad bottom by footer height */
  padding: 0 0 60px;
}

/* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
.footerfixed {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

javascript:

```
 if ($(window).height() > ($('#content').innerHeight() + $('#navigation').innerHeight() + $('#footer').innerHeight() ))
{
    $('#content').addClass('wrap');
    $('#footer').addClass('footerfixed');
}
```

Their seems no (or see: stackoverflow.com/a/17582746/1596547) pure CSS solution to fix this, see: [Sticky header, sticky footer (variable height), fluid middle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19220582/sticky-header-sticky-footer-variable-height-fluid-middle)