# Trouble with sticky footer, 2 column responsive layout with wide browser support

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, internet-explorer-9, sticky-footer

I need to create the following layout:

1. Two equal height columns
2. Sticky footer (positioned at bottom in light content, pushed off page in heavy content)
3. Responsive (left nav column collapses to 100% at mobile breakpoint)
4. Wide browser support (need to support down to IE9 but also mobile devices)

Desktop Layout:

[image: Desktop Layout]

Mobile Layout:

[image: Mobile Layout]

I've looked into many solutions for this and all of them really only solve for *some* of my needs. Haven't found a full solution yet. Not even the Holy Grail because many of those solutions use flexbox, CSS grid, or CSS tables and IE9 won't support those without a polyfill (which I *could* do, but for layout?!).

Comment: Why not look into bootstrap for this? That is the reason it was made. :)

Comment: what version of grails are you using?

Comment: Elixir, I'm not using Grails. This is in a java/Angular2 application. I was referring to Holy Grail layout referred to in this A List Apart article:
https://alistapart.com/article/holygrail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to have to settle on using CSS flexbox for this, then use a polyfill like [Flexibility](https://github.com/jonathantneal/flexibility) to gain older IE support.

Here's a working [Codepen](https://codepen.io/paulobrien/pen/rxyEMN), using Flexbox.

```css
html, body {
 margin:0;
 padding:0
}
.wrap {
 display: flex;
 min-height: 100vh;
 flex-direction: column;
 max-width:1200px;
  margin:auto;
}
.main {
 flex: 1;
 display:flex;
}
footer, header {
 background:green;
 padding:10px;
}
.sidebar {
 background:blue;
 flex:0 0 300px;
 padding:10px;
}
.content{
 background:yellow;
 padding:10px;
 flex:1; 
}
@media screen and (max-width:680px){
 .sidebar{flex: 0;order:0}
 .main {flex-direction:column;} 
}
```

```html
<!-- could use body element instead of wrap if wanted -->
<div class="wrap">
  <header>Header</header>
  <main class="main">
    <div class="sidebar">Sidebar Sidebar Sidebar Sidebar Sidebar Sidebar Sidebar Sidebar Sidebar Sidebar Sidebar Sidebar Sidebar Sidebar Sidebar Sidebar Sidebar Sidebar Sidebar Sidebar Sidebar Sidebar Sidebar Sidebar Sidebar Sidebar Sidebar </div>
    <div class="content">Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content </div>
  </main>
  <footer>footer - <a target="blank"  href="http://codepen.io/paulobrien/full/FKAxH/">See display table version of sticky footer</a></footer>
</div>
```

It would be nice to find a solution with pure CSS that can be supported by older IE, but I'm thinking that it's not worth the extra code bloat to get there, especially for a smaller percentage of users.

Answer (score 0):

You should try **CSSLayoutGenerator**:

http://csslayoutgenerator.com/

I was able to create a layout with a sticky footer like you are describing.

Comment: That's a decent tool, but it cannot achieve all of my requirements. For the footer, it gives you the choice between "Keep the footer at the bottom of browser window" or "Emulate equal height columns". I need both.

Comment: You should be able to achieve this with CSS: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19220042/1839504

Comment: That doesn't work either. The content doesn't push the footer beneath the page fold. Instead the footer covers the content, forcing it to scroll behind the footer.